# Get Command Sender onPlayerTeleport Bukkit

Tags: java, bukkit

I am working on something where I use the `OnPlayerTeleport` event and I've been trying to find a way to get the name of the player that sent the command. This is easy if the player teleported them self because obviously you could use `event.getPlayer()`.

When `player1` teleports `player2` to spawn, `player2` may fire the event. I need a way of returning the result back to `player1`, if the teleport was cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to the command, not its behavior.
You can use [`PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent.html).

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.MONITOR)
public void onCommand(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
    String label = event.getMessage();
    String[] components = label.split(" ");
    if (components[0].equalsIgnoreCase("/tp")) {
        Player sender = event.getPlayer();
        // Here you go
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you were to check for a user casting a command, you must assert that the command is either `/tp` or `/tp (something else but space there is necessary)`, otherwise you will catch up irrelevant commands like `/tptoggle` (from Essentials).

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the one who has written the command (/tp p1 p2), for example by a class extending JavaPlugin and containing

```
onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
```

In there, you should be able to detect who is the sender by checking for the args and sender you are given.

Comment: Hey i tried this and i couldn't get it to work the way i wanted it to. I need the event to fire on any command however it only fires on specific command. I need to fire on every one because its not my plugin that actually handles it. For example, the plugin "Multiverse" has its own teleport command.